# Ubuntu 22.04 KDE second monitor fails

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, kde

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04. With Ubuntu 20.04, my two monitors merged to create one desktop under KDE. With 22.04, the second monitor displays the KDE boot icon and then goes blank. This happens using Xorg or Wayland. When I boot GNOME under either Xorg or Wayland, the monitors merge as expected. I include Xorg.0.log and xrandr for both KDE and GNOME below.

[Xorg.0.log KDE](https://dpaste.com/FFYJR37U4) [Xorg.0.log GNOME](https://dpaste.com/E4LYKNF2T) [xrandr KDE](https://dpaste.com/4LFFBTK4R) [xrandr GNOME](https://dpaste.com/6TGKGRM88)

Any debugging hints will be gratefully accepted.

Comment: Open `Display Configuration` in system settings, and ensure that both screens are activated there.

Comment: @guiverc My box has one OS: Ubuntu only. It was recently upgraded to 22.04 from 20.04. It is multi-desktop: I can choose from SDDM (KDE's display manager) GNOME under Xorg, GNOME under Wayland, KDE under Xorg, and KDE under Wayland. It is running kernel 5.15.0-91-generic x86_64. It tried booting a live Kubuntu USB stick. It booted in Kubuntu but only one monitor displayed and there was no KDE menu.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Both are in these settings but manipulating the images of the monitors didn't help.

Comment: I'll suggest you check whilst using KDE Plasma (not other DE). As I stated earlier (*now deleted*) I'd check out using *live* media if it works as you want (*if it doesn't its a setting made on your config*); as you're using GA kernel stack (5.15) use 22.04/22.04.1 media only (22.04.3 will have the now *deprecated* 6.2 kernel, 22.04.4 the newly rolled out 6.5 kernel).  I don't know sorry..

Comment: @guiverc I couldn't find a 22.04/22.04.1 Kubuntu ISO so I created a 22.04.3 Kubuntu live USB. This booted correctly into KDE, including merged monitors. I then installed it but the problem continues. I am puzzled by why the problem occurs only using KDE and not GNOME.

Comment: Your re-installed your existing system, which with 22.04.2/22.04.3 (or later) media uses the HWE kernel; 22.04/22.04.1 used GA or 5.15 (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack). KDE Plasma uses a different stack (Qt5 & KF5) thus differs to GNOME (GTK), though kernel modules (aka *drivers*) will be identical.  If you did a clean install (*not saving your apps/configs*) that is useful knowledge; but if a non-destructive re-install (*what I'd have used*) your configs/settings will not have been touched thru re-install... You didn't specify what type of install

Comment: @guiverc I have an LVM mounted on /home. This was preserved in the Kubuntu 22.04.3 install but everything else was formatted and, hence, wiped out.

Comment: Have you tried the proprietary driver?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on desktop > Configure Display Settings... displayed both monitors. The left (primary) one had 60 Hz refresh rate and the right 75 Hz. When I changed the right one to 60 Hz, the right monitor displayed normally with the two monitors merged to create a single desktop.